# OpenERP module not showing in correct path

Tags: module, odoo, add-on

My module is not showing in the addon in this path that is

```
C:\Users\bakhtawar\workspace\abc\openerp-7.0-20130916-231138\
   openerp\addons
```

it is showing in this path

```
C:\Users\bakhtawar\workspace\abc\openerp-7.0-20130916-231138\
   build\lib\openerp\addons\Asset_Allocation.
```

I think if it will show in that path so then I can install my custom module that is asset_allocation.

Comment: here any body tell me about this problem?

Comment: Can u describe your problem in detail?